# JavaScript audio player plugin doubling markup in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-audio

I have an Angular app that pulls in many audio files from a database. I'm using audio.js by Anthony Kolber as the HTML5 player, where the associated wrapper and html are generated from the javascript. The problem is the markup is doubling and I can't figure out why. It does so both within or without an ng-repeat and causes a continuous 'undefined' error when setting width to the loading and progress bars.

The javascript is quite long and difficult to paste here. I've created a simplified version of the problem with the code [here](https://github.com/m-hatch/audioTest) as well as a live demo [here](http://montgomeryhatch.com/demos/audioTest/).

The original HTML:

```
<!-- audio links -->
<div ng-repeat="audio in medias | orderBy: 'track'" my-repeat-directive>
  <span><em>{{audio.title}}</em></span>
  <audio src="" dynamic-url dynamic-url-src="{{audio.url}}" preload="auto" />
</div>
```

The rendered HTM:

```
<div ng-repeat="audio in medias | orderBy: 'track'" my-repeat-directive="" class="ng-scope">
  <span><em class="ng-binding">Glass Jungle 1</em></span>

  <div class="audiojs loading" classname="audiojs" id="audiojs_wrapper0">

    <div class="audiojs " classname="audiojs" id="audiojs_wrapper3">

      <audio src="audio_files/Glass_Jungle_sample1.mp3" dynamic-url="" dynamic-url-src="Glass_Jungle_sample1.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

      <div class="play-pause">
       <p class="play"></p>             
       <p class="pause"></p>             
       <p class="loading"></p>             
       <p class="error"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="scrubber">
        <div class="progress" style="width: 0%;"></div>
        <div class="loaded" style="width: 100%;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="time">
        <em class="played">00:00</em>/<strong class="duration">01:25</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="error-message"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="play-pause">             
      <p class="play"></p>             
      <p class="pause"></p>             
      <p class="loading"></p>             
      <p class="error"></p>           
    </div>           
    <div class="scrubber">             
      <div class="progress"></div>             
      <div class="loaded"></div>           
    </div>           
    <div class="time">             
      <em class="played">00:00</em>/<strong class="duration">00:00</strong>           
    </div>           
    <div class="error-message"></div>

 </div>
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to intersperse jquery and angular. Have you tried in your repeat directive to, instead of setting ready to true, just executing the audiojs.createAll() (rather than conditionally inserting a script tag?)?

Comment: I know it's a bit hacky... I tried to make an audio player in Angular and just couldn't get it right. The difficulty is being able to get the data in the repeat on the client side. Yes, I did try executing the script in the repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded your code and simplified it a bit and it worked for me:

```html
<!-- audio links -->
<div ng-repeat="audio in medias | orderBy: 'track'">
  <span><em>{{audio.title}}</em></span>
  <audio src="" dynamic-url dynamic-url-src="{{audio.url}}" preload="auto" />
</div>

<!-- JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- angularJS -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- AngularJS Scripts -->
<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.medias = [{
      "track": 1,
      "title": "Glass Jungle 1",
      "url": "Glass_Jungle_sample1.mp3"
    }, {
      "track": 2,
      "title": "Glass Jungle 2",
      "url": "Glass_Jungle_sample2.mp3"
    }, {
      "track": 3,
      "title": "Glass Jungle 3",
      "url": "Glass_Jungle_sample3.mp3"
    }];

    audiojs.events.ready(function() {
      var as = audiojs.createAll();
    });

  });
  app.directive('dynamicUrl', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attr) {
        element.attr('src', 'audio_files/' + attr.dynamicUrlSrc);
      }
    };
  });
</script>
```

The rest is the same. I didn't delve too deeply into the whys of why your code was having problems, and it's been a while since I worked with angular, but I think it had to do with myRepeatDirective, which is executed 3 times, once for each audio file. I'm guessing the markup was only duplicated twice because the second time through it encountered the javascript errors to prevent it from executing a third time.

Comment: You're right! It was the myRepeatDirective... All that was necessary was to delete that. The concern was if there is a large number of audio tags being loaded that the audiojs script not be run prematurely. The repeat directive was a hacky way to signal the end of the ng-repeat. I do not know of any other way to watch for this. As it stands, it seems to work because of a risky setTimeout around the `audiojs.createAll()` .